# Building colorful tags in a tag cloud?

Tags: css, tags

For example, I have a tag cloud like this,

```
<div class="tagcloud"> 
<a href="#" class="tag-link-79">tag1</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag-link-78">tag2</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag-link-35">tag3</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag-link-32">tag4</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag-link-29">tag5</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag-link-30">tag6</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag-link-34">tag7</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag-link-31">tag8</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag-link-33">tag9</a> 
</div>
```

Each of them with a different/random class, and display in random colors(it's background), but all the colors were chosen in default.

Yes I know it's impossible with pure css, any solutions?

Comment: try mixing it jquery since you know its impossible in pure css

Comment: I think you'll need some JavaScript to make it nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random colors for background:

```
var tags = [].slice.call(document.querySelector('.tagcloud')
                         .getElementsByTagName('a'));

tags.forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
});

function randomColor() {
    return  '#' + (0x1000000 + (Math.random()) * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1, 6);
}
```

JSFiddle example:

**http://jsfiddle.net/dL0hb3ar/**